# limiting the number of chars scanf will read using a define value

Tags: c, input, scanf

I want to limit the number of chars scanf command will get using a define value. 
The following code worked well

```
scanf("%20s",&stud->student_name);
```

but then i have tried that one (MAXNAMELEN is defiend as 20)

```
scanf("%MAXNAMELENs",&stud->student_name);
```

and it didn't work.
how can I do that using scanf only ?

Comment: You can generate a format string first with `sprintf`, or (better) use `fgets`.

Comment: You could always `#define MAXNAMELENFORMATSTRING "%20s"` as a very simple option.

Answer (score 1):

A pair of `define`s allow for stringifying another `define`

```
#define MAXNAMELEN 20
#define LENSTR_(x) #x
#define LENSTR(x) LENSTR_(x)
```

use as

```
char str[MAXNAMELEN + 1] = "";
result = scanf ( "%"LENSTR(MAXNAMELEN)"s", str);
```